# Are boost UUIDs generated using default mt19937 RNG secure for session IDs?

Tags: c++, security, boost, uuid, boost-uuid

I need to generate UUIDs for use as non-predictable / guessable session IDs.

This can easily be accomplished using [boost's UUID library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/uuid/):

```
boost::uuids::uuid newUUID()
{
  static boost::uuids::random_generator gen;
  return gen();
}
```

The returned UUID can easily be converted to a string.

The above code is equivalent to:

```
boost::uuids::uuid newUUID()
{
  static boost::uuids::basic_random_generator<boost::mt19937> gen;
  return gen();
}
```

So we are using the Mersenne Twister 19937 pseudo random number generator. It looks like boost takes the task of [seeding it properly](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/uuid/seed_rng.hpp) serious.

However, I wonder if something important – security wise – is gained by using a non-deterministic RNG like [boost::random_device](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/random/random_device.html) instead, and also how it will impact the speed of UUID generation.

```
boost::uuids::uuid newUUID()
{
  static boost::uuids::basic_random_generator<boost::random_device> gen;
  return gen();
}
```

Advice from people with security insight is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by secure?  AFAIK it is not cryptographically secure.

Comment: MT is really fast and pretty high quality, but it is not a crypto RNG. Speed will not be an issue though, MT can generate GBs of random data per second on normal systems.

Comment: @NathanOliver That is really the question: is it necessary to use a crypto RNG for generating UUIDs if these are going to be used for session IDs that should not be predictable / guessable or is MT secure enough for this purpose.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Many common ones provide a means of generating UUIDs which they do with the added bonus of practically guaranteeing non-duplication.

Comment: @Bathsheba Many different (Linux, AIX, Windows, Mac OS X). But the issue is not uniqueness but predictability. See Yakk's answer and comments below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MT is not a cryptographically secure RNG.

`boost::random_device` is guaranteed (by docs) to only exist if cruptographically secure and non-deterministic.  Note that this is not true of `std::random_device`.

For any serious application, you cannot trust a mere documented guarantee.  But for a small scale unimportant one it should do.

Writing your own cryptographically secure code or system is usually a bad idea.  Describe how bad it is that someone defeat your system, as that really matters to how much effort you need to put into it.

Comment: Ok, so for generating UUIDs that just needs to be unique, MT is perfect and fast, but for UUIDs that should be non-predictable / guessable like a session ID, is a crypto RNG needed? We are not talking about generating a crypto key but about a session ID that should not be guessable.

Comment: You could use the string-generator and feed it data from `std::random_device` or `/dev/urandom`

Comment: @mgd Non-crypto secure means that someone with modest information can reverse the function.  Like, find the next/previous one after a given one, or find a pattern after a modest selection of values.  I did not address if MT would generate sufficiently unique values to have a low chance of repeats of your UUIDs.  I would assume so, but I am not going to assert it without double checking.  Note that the above presumes that the UUID generator from RNG isn't completely stupid: a stupid UUID generator can make the quality of the RNG irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So, non-crypto secure means that someone with access to one session ID can guess another one which is not acceptable. (I understand the difference between generating unique IDs and generating non-predictable unique IDs.)

Comment: @mgd **no**
, it means it is not suitable for situations where security matters in any way, shape or form.  To a first approximation, you should assume the counter party can predict everything it does (its output in every situation).  If that is a problem, don't use it.  There may be finer grained facts that are less extreme, but **I will not give you any such guarantee**, nor should I, even if I thought I knew the answer.  If you care *at all* about security, don't assume *anything* of non-crypto secure components.  I gave an example of a hole, **I did not guarantee that is the only hole**.

Comment: I agree. Instead of saying “non-crypto secure means…” I should have said “non-crypto secure among other things implies no guarantees wrt predictability”. Thanks for taking the time to help.